# strip and replace - symbol from url echo

Tags: php

I am using the following to echo out current url.

```
function curPageURL() {

$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$url = explode('/', $url);
$lastPart = array_pop($url);

return $lastPart;
}

$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
echo curPageURL();
```

but some urls are formatted using -
for example

www. xxxxxxx.xom/category/abc-123

I need to remove the - between the abc-123 and echo abc 123. Just replacing the - with a space.

Thanks

Comment: So `str_replace("-"," ", $url);` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `str_replace`

```
function curPageURL() {
    .
    .
    .
    return str_replace("-", " ", $lastPart);
}
```

Comment: is there a method I could use to also make the first letter in each word uppercase. Thanks

Comment: system wont let me accept answer for another 6 mins.

Comment: Just use `ucwords(str_replace("-", " ", $lastPart));`